# How to display partial view on button click in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I am developing my application in MVC. I am using single text and button. On clicking a button i need to send the email and to show the partial view.

Controller Code

```
public ActionResult BusinessUserRegister()
        {

            return View();

        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult BusinessUserRegister(string Emailid)
        {
            string userId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserTypeId"];
            int typeid = Convert.ToInt32(userId);

            EmailManager.SendConfirmationEmail(Emailid);
            tbl_BusinessUser user = new tbl_BusinessUser();
            user.RandomNumber = (int)Session["rd"];
            user.EmailId = Emailid;
            db.tbl_BusinessUser.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            //return View();
            return PartialView("BusinessUserVerifyPartial");

        }
```

View

```
@model SYTMain.Models.tbl_BusinessUser

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "BusinessUserRegister";
}

<h2>BusinessUserRegister</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

        <div class="sign2" style="height:267px;width:562px;margin-left:214px" id="emaildiv">
            @*@Html.TextBox("EmailId", "", new { @placeholder = "Enter the Email ", id = "txtemail" })<br /><br />*@
            <input type="text" name="Emailid" id="Email"/>
          <input type="button" name="submit" value="Sign Up" id="Emailbtn"  class="addbutton" />
        </div>


    <div id=" Emailverify" >


    </div>


} 
@section Scripts{


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#Emailbtn").click(function () {
            debugger;
            var url = '@Url.Action("BusinessUserRegister", "BU")';

            $.post(url, { Emailid: $('#Email').val() }, function (data) {
               //   alert(data);

                $("#Emailverify").html(data);
            });


        })

    </script>

}
```

Partial View

```
 <div id="EmailVerify">
        <div class="sign3" style="height:267px;width:562px;margin-left:214px" id="verfieddiv">
            @Html.TextBox("verify", "", new { @placeholder = "Enter the Random Number", id = "txtverified" })<br /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="Verify" value="Verify" id="vbtn" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

My problem is Partial View is not displaying on clicking a button.

On clicking a button Email is sending to the corresponding user and the same page is displaying, partial view is not getting loaded.

Comment: You have hidden it using `$("#Emailverify").hide();` There is no point in that line of code since there is nothing initially to display anyway - just remove it.

Comment: I removed that, but my partial view is not getting displayed.

Comment: What if any errors are you getting in the browser console. And its hard to understand what you think your trying to do with this code. If it works all you adding is a textbox and a submit button and when you click the submit button you will call exactly the same method but you not using the value of the `verify` textbox.

Answer (score 0):

For beginning remove white space before "Emailverify"

```
<div id=" Emailverify" >
```

And why are you using Html.BeginForm(), if you using JQuery code to send and receive data from server? Probably you wanted to use type="submit" instead of name="submit". Clicking confirm button will send form to BusinessUserRegister action and as result refresh all your page and you start from beginning. My advice is to remove Html.BeginForm() and white space.